Is the biblical term "God" a denotation for a specific lifeform, or a title?
I’m looking at this from a purely biblical perspective.
“God is a spirit” (John 4:24)
A spirit is a (for humans) invisible supernatural lifeform.
Thayer's Greek Lexicon describes the lifeform as:


"a spirit, i. e. a simple essence, devoid of all or at least all grosser matter, and possessed of the power of knowing, desiring,
deciding, and acting";


In connection with God, however, mainstream Christology often uses the term “nature of God” or “divine nature”, especially when it comes to describing the triune God’s essence or substance, as it is found in Christ who is said to be the "God-man" in the hypostatic union, having both a fully human and a fully divine nature. Considering myself a human, I think to understand what is meant by "human" nature, as being part of the human species/lifeform.
The term “divine nature” however seems quite abstract, and is found only once in the Bible, in 2 Peter 1:4

by which have been given to us exceedingly great and precious
promises, that through these you may be partakers of the divine
nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through
lust.

Re-born Christians have the “great and precious promise” of being “partakers of the divine nature”.
They „shall be like Him (God)“ (1. John 3:2).
One could conclude from this that Christians who become "partakers of the divine nature", inherit the divine nature when they go to heaven, and thus become fully God, if the term "God" is to be understood as a lifeform. On this point, I think most mainstream Christians would agree, that this is not the case - heavenly resurrected Christians don't become the "God" lifeform, but the "spirit" lifeform.

It is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. There is a
natural body, and there is a spiritual body.
As was the man of dust, so also are those who are made of dust; and as
is the heavenly Man, so also are those who are heavenly. And as we
have borne the image of the man of dust, we shall also bear the image
of the heavenly Man. (1. Corinthians 15:44,48-49)

Hence the question: the only time the Bible speaks of the "divine nature" it is clear that from a biblical standpoint it means the lifeform of "incorruptible spiritual bodies".
So is "God" a type of lifeform as appears to be the understanding and intermittent use of the term by people believing in the homoousion, or is it a general title that the one Almighty God carries in the highest possible sense?

" the only time the Bible speaks of the "divine nature" it is clear that from a biblical standpoint it means the lifeform of "incorruptible spiritual bodies".  Perhaps this is not as clear as you have supposed.  This could just as easily (coupled with verse 3) be referring to the promise of the Spirit and the fruit thereof.   It is things pertaining to life and godliness, not ultimate shape or form.

@MikeBorden The term 'divine nature' is used (2 Peter 1:3,4) in a context where it is clearly in regard to Divine Righteousness. That is the nature of Deity.

One could conclude from this that Christians who become "partakers of the divine nature", inherit the divine nature when they go to heaven, and thus become fully God, if the term "God" is to be understood as a lifeform. On this point, I think most mainstream Christians would agree, that this is not the case - heavenly resurrected Christians don't become the "God" lifeform, but the "spirit" lifeform. I cannot think of any Christian group that holds anything like this.

@NigelJ So what do Christians become when resurrected in heaven? Do they keep their human bodies? Or do they get spiritual bodies (1. Corinthians 15:44)? If they have spiritual bodies in heaven, are they not spirits, like the heavenly Angels (Hebrews 1:7)?

@MikeBorden - I don't think that's what the immediate context of 2Peter 1:3,4 is saying - verse 2 speaks about knowledge of God and Jesus, referring to Jesus' words in John 17:3 that this knowledge means eternal life. Verse 3 speaks about God's power helping human Christians in living a godly life in knowing God, which again brings blessings and leads to eternal life. This promise of eternal life includes them partaking in "divine nature" which is an "incorruptible and undefiled and unfading inheritance...reserved in the heavens" (1. Peter 1:4)

Those who 'partake of the Divine nature' are they who, by faith, are accounted receivers of the Righteousness of God (they are the justified). This is partaking of the Divine nature.

Abraham‘s faith was counted to him as righteousness by God (James 2) - does that mean he became partaker in divine nature? Where do the justified go after they die, and what lifeform will they become?

"heavenly resurrected Christians don't become the "God" lifeform, but the "spirit" lifeform" and yet the resurrection of the body is a belief held by many Christians as well.

God - according to the bible - is a spirit lifeform. Heavenly resurrected persons become spirit lifeforms as well - they will be like God and see Him. There is no distinct „God“ lifeform, there are only divine attributes and qualities that make the Almighty God a unique member of the spirit lifeform. The terminology used for God‘s uniqueness often implies that he is a different lifeform than all other spiritual beings which is wrong. He is different and unique in his attributes and qualities (just as any person whether human or spiritual being is) but not in the lifeform.

This is a somewhat loaded question, assuming doctrines (e.g. "hypostatic union", "re-born", "go to heaven", and "Christians don't become the "God") that overly complicate the issue, and that for the most part don't need to be part of the question.

@RayButterworth - I agree that this might not be the only interpretation out there, but it is what is widely accepted in mainstream Christianity. I am open for any responses - also the ones that don't share the majority view on this topic.

In the Bible, the word 'God' predominantly identifies the eternal Spirit who created everything. Sometimes it refers to pagan ideas of their gods, which they give names to (such as Ashtoreth etc). But those are only supposed deities. They don't actually exist, according to the Bible. Satan the devil is called "god of this system of things" however, and he is a real, invisible spirit, but a false god, a would-be-usurper-god who deceives humanity. Another instance where the word means 'mighty ones' is given to men who are appointed by God to represent him on Earth, such as the Kings and Judges of Israel. There is no actual deity ascribed to such men. Only the Creator God is called Jehovah God, or Yahweh, and this by his chosen people.
As for "the nature of God", which you ask about, "the divine nature" - the simplest way of cutting out all the clutter of theological wording is to consider first what human nature is. All humans have human nature, as opposed to animal nature. God created humans "in his image", giving the first man life. Life begets life. No life can come from a non-living source. The living God imparted life to humanity, and also enabled them to procreate - to have children who would share their human nature. That, however, did not make their children the same person as their human father! Personhood is one thing. Nature is another. A person always has the nature of the one whose life they share. Some people even look like their father (or their mother). "He's the spitting image of his Dad!" goes the saying. But it is characteristics that count, showing the nature of the father to also be in the person of the offspring.
When the Bible speaks of the nature of God, it is dealing with his divine characteristics, his divine qualities that are unique to him. God, in his very being, is Righteous. That is the quality of the one true God. God is Light. God is Love. God is Life. God cannot be untrue to himself, therefore he cannot be unrighteous, he cannot lie, he cannot judge unfairly, he cannot stop being holy - that sort of thing.
This means that the Son of the Father has always shared this divine nature, even though there is distinction of person. The person of the Father is not the same person as the Son. Yet because the divine life is unique to the divine being of God, that one, unique divine nature is equally in the Father as it is in the Son - which is why Jesus declared that he is "the Life"!.
The one Almighty God is a complex being, which is why what it says about the Son is staggering. We learn from the Bible that the Son is eternal, uncreated (which you may well disagree with) but before anyone can grasp what the hypostatic union means, they have to grasp that the framers of such theological language believed that three Persons share the divine nature. The Father and the Son share the one, divine nature, with absolute unity of the Holy Spirit in that nature. To disagree with that will make it impossible to grasp what the hypostatic union is.
This is why I cannot take this answer any further forward, for you. All I can do is summarize. When the Creator is acclaimed as uniquely righteous in his being, and we grasp that the Word of God made everything that was made (John 1:3) and later became flesh as the man Jesus, we see that the Word - the Son of God - is also righteous in his being. The Bible shows that those who put faith in the righteousness of God demonstrated at Golgotha and the empty tomb, are declared righteous in his sight, even while on Earth. Not due to anything they have done; nobody can earn or merit such a standing before God, but he is pleased to bring such believers into spiritual newness of life; born from above of the Spirit. They are then in the family of God, relating to God as children of God.
Yet they can never be equal to God (the satanic lie in the garden of Eden). They cannot share the divine nature in the unique way that the only-begotten Son of God does. Humans all had a starting point in time. The Son never did. And we are back to the stumbling-block that prevents understanding of the hypostatic union. Those who say the Son was created as a creature by God, will never get it. So, I have to stop here.
But the answer to your query is that the divine nature is not "a specific life-form". It is the very essence of who the one Creator is. It is WHO he is, not WHAT he is. THIS God is unique in his being, so that no created life (even though born again from above) can ever share the being of God, the nature of God, as does the uncreated, eternal Son of God.

While I don’t agree with the statement that „nature“ is equal to „characteristics“ and „qualities“ especially if they are set to be unique in which case only one person can fit them (in my opinion). I always thought the Trinity spoke about 1 what (God) and 3 whos - anyways, I like your respectful and clear exposition. It’s ultimately not fathomable for me (and I guess you might say it isn’t meant to be) but I respect the position. +1

@Js Witness  Noted. I've just answered this related Q, with 2 quotes that may help you fathom the matter about the Son of God, and a way of approach to this vexed question of whether he had a starting point in time, or not. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/101767/what-is-the-best-way-for-christian-theologians-to-describe-the-concept-of-god-wh/101778#101778
